# C++ fmt lib. Partial arguments substitution

Tags: c++, fmt

I have a single big template (loaded from file) in which I'm supposed to replace named arguments with their actual values. The issue is that I need to do it in two different functions, so part of the named arguments need to be substituted in `func1()` and part - in `func2()`.

The desired behavior is that the following below returns `myarg1 myarg2`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <fmt/core.h>

std::string func1(std::string& templ) {
    return fmt::format(templ, fmt::arg("arg1", "myarg1"));
}

std::string func2(std::string& templ) {
    return fmt::format(templ, fmt::arg("arg2", "myarg2"));
}

int main() {
    std::string templ = "{arg1} {arg2}";
    templ = func1(templ);
    templ = func2(templ);

    std::cout << templ << std::endl;
}
```

However I get
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'fmt::v6::format_error' what():  argument not found` inside the first function.

Is there a way to do partial/gradual arguments substitution in `fmt` ?

Comment: `fmt::format` is not a search-and-replace function.You are using a wrong library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, {fmt} requires all arguments to be passed in one call.

Comment: Thanks! Great lib nevertheless.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it! You have to make sure that your `{arg2}` survives `func1` by escaping the brackets, e. g. `{{arg2}}`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <fmt/core.h>

std::string func1(std::string& templ) {
    return fmt::format(templ, fmt::arg("arg1", "myarg1"));
}

std::string func2(std::string& templ) {
    return fmt::format(templ, fmt::arg("arg2", "myarg2"));
}

int main() {
    std::string templ = "{arg1} {{arg2}}";
    templ = func1(templ);
    templ = func2(templ);

    std::cout << templ << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This suggestion works great. Thank you.